# Joomla can't update. "Update: :Extension: Could not open https://update.joomla.org/core/extension.xml"

Tags: php, joomla, openssl

Just using Joomla for the first time. I need to perform an update. On the Control Panel page, I select the icon to automatically install the newest updates; on the next page I hit the update button. Joomla fails to automatically update. Instead it simply prints

> Update: :Extension: Could not open https://update.joomla.org/core/extension.xml

Nothing was logged in my Joomla error logs. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your `php.ini` file (probably located in your PHP install directory), make sure that `extension=php_openssl.dll` is present and NOT commented out with a semicolon. This extension is necessary in order for Joomla to make an https call to its update server.

Second, still in your `php.ini` file, make sure the `allow_url_fopen` property is turned "on". If this is off, Joomla will not be allowed to download files from its update server.

Finally, in your `configuration.php` file (probably located in your web server's root folder), ensure that `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so` is present and NOT commented out with a hashtag. I don't know what this line does, but it seems to be necessary.